# Reconstruction of hyperbolic curves using the fundamental group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-curves, fundamental-group, anabelian-geometry

In the paper [Curves and their Fundamental Groups](http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1997-1998__40__131_0.pdf) written by Gerd Faltings, Mochizuki's proof of Grothendick's conjecture on anabelian curves is explained.

In the proof, he shows that for two hyperbolic curves $X$ and $Y$, if there exists an isomorphism between the algebraic fundamental groups $\pi_1(X)$ and $\pi_1(Y)$ then these curves are isomorphic.

My question is: With only the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$, can the hyperbolic curve $X$ be reconstructed? Specifically can the differential sheaf $\omega_X$ be reconstructed using only the algebraic fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$?

Answer (score 2):

The way to reconstruct the differential sheaf from the fundamental group is, of course,

$$\pi_1(X)\curvearrowright X\curvearrowright \omega_X$$

But I don't think you can get to the differential sheaf directly, without passing through the underlying curve at some point. At least not with Mochizuki's original result alone.

Perhaps $\omega_X$ can be carved out of $\pi_1(X)$ with the techniques of mono anabelian reconstruction (see Topics in absolute anabelian geometry III), but that's a different story.

Not sure if that helps.

I think the same should apply to any other piece of relevant information from $X$. Ultimately, only $\pi_1(X)$ is anabelian enough.

Comment: What does it mean to 'reconstruct the differential sheaf directly' if you don't know what $X$ is? I don't think this is what the OP is asking. (Although maybe 'anabelian reconstruction' is all the OP is looking for.)